# Use Django model IntegerField validator values on the form

Tags: django, validation, django-models, django-forms

I am able to set the minimum value validator on the model:

```
class MyModel(Model):
    my_field = models.fields.IntegerField(default=250, validators=[MinValueValidator(30)])
```

Then I create a form using the previous model:

```
class MyForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('my_field',)
```

The form gets validated, the correct error message is displayed (when entered value is <30), but even when entered wrong value, it gets saved on the instance!

I was able to make it work by specifying (again) the min value on the form:

```
class MyForm(ModelForm):
    my_field = form.IntegerField(min_value=30)

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('my_field',)
```

But this way the code is not dry - I need to specify the value and field type twice.

Is there any way I could avoid this? Or at least get the min_value from the model validator?

Answer (score 1):

Validators don't have anything to do with saving the model - other than the fact they should be checked before saving.

[docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/validators/#how-validators-are-run)

> Note that validators will not be run automatically when you save a model, but if you are using a ModelForm, it will run your validators on any fields that are included in your form.

Either ensure that you are strict with how you allow objects to be created or you may need to override save or provide a [pre_save signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.pre_save)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How come the "form_invalid" gets fired then, stating that "something's wrong", but the instance gets saved anyways?

Comment: @Julius - Thats nothing to do with validators, its most likely a bug in your own code, form_invalid doesn't call save

Comment: @Julius - Random stab in the dark but I'm guessing that your `form_invalid` is calling `super.form_valid`

Comment: No, it's not - checked that already :) I think I found the problem... My instance is referred from the Site, that is, my get_form looks like this: return form_class(instance=get_current_site(self.request).configuration, **self.get_form_kwargs()) Now I believe that changed values are set and stay until I restart the server. Is there a way to reset the form?

Comment: @Julius - That would be a different question for which you should raise a new question for it if needed

Answer (score 0):

I think all the problem you have is this **.fields** you added, and you didn't call models.Model properly. Every other thing seem to be in order.
my_field = models**.fields**.IntegerField(default=250, validators=[MinValueValidator(30)])

Try this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_field = models.IntegerField(default = '250', validators = MinValueValidator(30)])
```